# How to refer to files above Jasmine tests root folder?

Tags: java, ruby, unit-testing, jasmine

I have Java project and we will use jasmine gem to test. But, I cant refer to any javascript above the Jasmine root folder path. Like:

All my javascripts are under /src/main/webapp/resources/js and my jasmine folder is under /src/test/unit/js.

I tried changing jasmine.yml to move to ../../../main/webapp/resources/js but didnt work.

How can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So It was only a setup problem. To make it work there is a jasmine.yml and there just changed the src_dir to top folder using "../../../".

After that, change src_files to main/xxxxxx/xxxxx/*.js

That's all!